# Tab Layout and buttons in Android

Tags: java, android, button

I have built an application in android using Tab Layout and it has 2 tabs. I want a different button on each of these tabs. But if I define button in main.xml, I get same button on both the tabs.

I even tried defining the buttons separately in the class of each tab, but was getting some weird errors. can somebody please help me out with this. Below is my code:

***FinalProj.java:***

```
package FinalProj.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class FinalProj extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, iFallApp.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Settings.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
}
```

***For Tab1 - iFallApp.java***

```
package FinalProj.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class iFallApp extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is the iFall tab");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

***Tab 2 - Settings.java***

```
package FinalProj.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Settings extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is the Settings tab");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

***Main.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
             <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I want to have one button along with TextView in iFallApp.java and one button and editText in Settings.java.

Comment: I solved this issue... Please don't bother... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else finding this question:

```
public class FinalProj extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

The `setContentView(R.layout.main)` tells the activity what to display on its UI. In this case the view is being set to load from R.layout.main which corresponds to /layout/main.xml (R being the generated lookup class generated by the android framework).

Changing the main.xml would change both tabs because both tabs are contained /within/ the `FinalProj` activity inside the `TabHost` view defined inside of `main.xml` here:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

The whole tab system is described in full detail here:
[Tab Layout | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

Comment: Thanks, this one helped me. Changing the main is what I needed to do!